# Transfer of test Airflow to the production environment

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I need to transfer the test Airflow to the production environment, but I cannot understand the sequence of steps.

The first thing I did was merge the test Git lab with all the DAGs into the production Git lab. All the DAGs were pulled into the production Airflow.

Question: Do I need to make a connection to the same database (PostgreSQL) that the test Airflow is connected to, or to a different database?

Please tell me about your cases related to transferring Airflow.

1. Merged the repositories.
2. I have not set up the connection yet.

Comment: Change connection properties in the production airflow to point to production DB. Do not hardcode credentials, use [`hook`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/connections.htm) object instead to retrieve connection.